# What format does the NUnit test results XML need to be to publish back to TFS 2010 build?

Tags: tfs, nunit, tfsbuild, xunit

I have some xUnit tests running as part of a build and I need to post the results back to TFS 2010 so they show up in the build summary/log like normal tests would.

I execute the tests with the `-nunit` argument so that the output is an NUnit xml and not a xUnit one. I'm trying to use NUnit4TeamBuild to publish the results xml back to TFS and it looks like it's working but there's no test results anywhere at the end.

This is the detailed log for that step:

```
Publish xUnit Results
NUnitTfs.exe -n results.xml -t Project -b "Build_20171221.8" -v 2010
Loading NUnit Output from results.xml...
Transforming NUnit output to .trx file...
Adding build information to .trx file...
Publishing .trx file...
Checking test run does not exist...
Reading users identity...
Creating test run...
Creating test results...
Updating test run with details...
Uploading test run details...
Uploading assemblies...
Updating test results with details...
Uploading test result details...
```

The build finishes with 0 errors and 0 warnings but also says "***No Test Results***" in the build summary and there are no test results anywhere.

I have no idea why the tests aren't publishing.

Here's an example of the XML that it's trying to publish (note that I've changed the file paths and shortened the stack trace):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test-results name="Test results" errors="0" inconclusive="0" ignored="0" invalid="0" not-run="0" date="2017-12-21" time="08:39:57" total="1" failures="1" skipped="0">
  <environment os-version="unknown" platform="unknown" cwd="unknown" machine-name="unknown" user="unknown" user-domain="unknown" nunit-version="xUnit.net 2.3.1.3858" clr-version="64-bit .NET 4.0.30319.34209 [collection-per-class, non-parallel]" />
  <culture-info current-culture="unknown" current-uiculture="unknown" />
  <test-suite type="Assemblies" name="C:\Tests.DLL" executed="True" success="False" result="Failure" time="57.41">
    <results>
      <test-suite type="Assembly" executed="True" name="C:\Tests.DLL" result="Failure" success="False" time="57.410">
        <results>
          <test-suite type="TestCollection" executed="True" name="Tests" result="Failure" success="False" time="48.992">
            <results>
              <test-case name="Google_Search_Test" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="48.9917024">
                <failure>
                  <message>System.Exception : Test Failed. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</message>
                  <stack-trace>at Tests.Fixtures.Fixture.FormatException(Exception e) in... etc. </stack-trace>
                </failure>
              </test-case>
            </results>
          </test-suite>
        </results>
      </test-suite>
    </results>
  </test-suite>
</test-results>
```

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2010 uses a proprietary results format with a “`.trx`” extension to publish results so we need to transpose the NUnit results before sending back through web services.

You can use [NUnitTFS for xUnit](http://blog.strobaek.org/2011/10/18/more-on-tfs-and-xunit/), just try the workflow template [NUnitAndPublishTemplate.xaml](https://gist.github.com/ianbattersby/1559622) which provided by **Ian Battersby**.

Refer to **Ian Battersby**'s blog for details : [Running and publishing NUnit test results into TFS 2010](http://ianbattersby.github.io/blog/2012/01/04/tfsbuild-2010-nunit-integration/)

Comment: As it says in the build log above: `Transforming NUnit output to .trx file...
Adding build information to .trx file...
Publishing .trx file...`

And I have already seen all 3 of those links you provided. Still no dice.

Comment: @J.Doe Is it possible that you did not set the correct permission to see the test result? See this link : http://blog.ehn.nu/2010/10/why-cant-i-see-test-results-in-the-tfs-2010-build-report/